# How to redirect to a different page, and change the referrer midway?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

Is it possible to do the following?

1. Visitor browses `page1.com`
2. Visitor clicks on link found on page1.com and is redirect to `example1.com`

Is it possible to change te referrer so the owner of example1.com doesn't see that the visitor came from page1.com, but instead another custom referrer, ex: rock&roll.com?

Thanks.

This works using Javascript, but it takes too long to load, and some visitors might have Javascript rendering off.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (i.e. _what are you afraid of?_)

Comment: I want to redirect visitors, and hide/change referrer from the initial page.

Comment: In HTML, you can use `rel="noreferrer"`. I don't think there's such another solution in HTML.

Comment: Will this work 100% of the time, every time? Also, is this instant? A 301 redirect is pretty much instant but can't change the referrer.

Comment: _"and hide/change referrer from the initial page"_ - yes, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: Hide affiliate links

Comment: ...why on earth would you want to _break_ affiliate-scheme links?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`noreferrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#noreferrer) and the [`nofollow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#nofollow) keywords on the [`rel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel) attribute.

```html
<a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Yo, I'm Google!</a>
```

Citing from MDN on the [`noreferrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#noreferrer) keyword:

> Relevant to [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), and [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area), including this value makes the referrer unknown (no `Referer` header will be included), and creates a top-level browsing context as if `noopener` were also set.

And on the [`nofollow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#nofollow) keyword:

> Relevant to [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), and [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area), the `nofollow` keyword tells search engine spiders to ignore the link relationship. The nofollow relationship may indicate the current document's owner does not endorse the referenced document. It is often included by Search Engine Optimizers pretending their link farms are not spam pages.